# How to append multiple ODS html exports into single HTML file?

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide

I'm exporting multiple datasets using ODS html (example below).
It saves HTML files on the server and in order to attach them to email.

The code is used to export looks like this:

```
ods html file="/user_data/maexport/generated_html.html";
proc print data=WORK.DATA_SET_0001;
run;
ods html close;
```

Now how can I append these multiple proc printed HTMLs into single HTML file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put all your prints before your ODS close statement.